# How to use custom EC parameters with java.security.KeyPairGenerator?

Tags: java, elliptic-curve, key-pair

I would like to use the Edwards curve "Curve41417" ([safecurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/)) for key pair generation.

Right now I have converted it to Weierstrass format and tried the following source code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
            keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "LunaProvider");

            // Create a secure random number generator using the SHA1PRNG algorithm
            SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

            //generator with the given parameter set and source of randomness
            keyGen.initialize(curve41417InHex(),secureRandomGenerator);

            //keyGen.initialize(ecSpec);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static ECParameterSpec curve41417InHex(){
        ECPoint point = new ECPoint(
                // gx
                new BigInteger("36AF93BFF765C2150A948827D97CF68F5F83E0D0C7411AE313A89ABF50224BBAE8C2F76271040290884CF5629DAB279D49AB0F98",16),
                // gy
                new BigInteger("1952C13B138703B04EA0D313944A8B1E9AE7882380AD83907F12F2A937C2503ADA9E6BF01CA1F76FDF9032C79F130EB2BEA4C102",16));

        final ECParameterSpec curve41417 = new ECParameterSpec(

                new EllipticCurve(
                        // field the finite field that this elliptic curve is over.
                        new ECFieldFp(new BigInteger("3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEF",16)),
                        // a : the first coefficient of this elliptic curve.
                        new BigInteger("3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBD324",16),
                        // b : the second coefficient of this elliptic curve.
                        new BigInteger("3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC3EC75",16)
                        ),
                point,
                // Order n
                new BigInteger("7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEB3CC92414CF706022B36F1C0338AD63CF181B0E71A5E106AF79",16),
                // Cofactor
                8);
        return curve41417;
    } 

}
```

The ouput for the previous source code is: Exception during Key Generation - Unsupported curve: java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec@43814d18

I believe I am either doing something wrong in the conversion from Montgomery to Weierstrass equation, or I am not using the proper classes to provide custom EC parameters.

Does somebody already succeeded in using custom EC parameters for key pair generation ? Perhaps for another Montgomery or Edwards curve ?

Comment: Curve41417 seems to be a (Twisted) Edwards Curve. Java JCE has not supported Edwards Curves and "Short" Weierstrass only for selected key lengthes, excluding 414 bits! Did not crosscheck your parameter transform. Formula Database is here https://hyperelliptic.org/  .  Consider that a KeyAgreement for compatibility should perform corresponding point transform; else if both ends run with Weierstrass the concept should be fine. Public Key encoding PKCS#xy is another story.   Also consider that performance driven curve design will not carry over to the Weierstrass shape.

Answer (score 1):

I believe is not possible to generate EC key pairs based on custom EC curves in LunaProvider using Luna's JSP API. However, it is possible to generate EC key pairs using JCProv API(by Luna). [JCProv](http://leifj.people.sunet.se/007-011136-007_lunasa_5-4-1_docs_revC/Content/sdk/java/jcprov.htm) - PKCS#11 Java Wrapper which is a lower level API close to PKCS#11 implementation. You can use CryptokiEx.C_GenerateKey(..) method to generate key pairs. PKSC#11 C_GenerateKey() method documentation can be found [here](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/).

Comment: C_GenerateKey is used to generating secret keys, not keypairs. use C_GenerateKeyPair